# Json value is returned with value noneType causing the code to fail. How does one make it more robust

Tags: python, json, request

I have the following JSON which i am getting using REST API

looks something like this

```
"itineraryIntent": {
    "itineraryId": 2446,
    "userNodes": [
      {
        "user": {
          "id": "-2",
          "givenName": "Wiliam Never",
          "preferredAirport": "",
          "travelerGroupId": null,
          "externalId": null,
          "externalId2": null,
          "checkCCFieldForTraveler": false,
          "notificationEmailOverride": null,
          "paxType": 0,
          "title": "Dr",
          "middleName": null,
          "dateOfBirth": "1980-01-15T00:00:00Z",
          "phoneNumber": null,
          "tsaInfo": null,
          "source": "RequestEndPoint",
          "allowBookingGuestTraveler": null,
          "gdsTravelerProfileContainsFirstName": false,
          "profilesFound": {
            "Agency": null,
            "Corporate": null,
            "Traveler": null
          },
          "userId": "-2",
          "firstName": "Wiliam",
          "lastName": "Never"
        },
        "elements": []
```

I am using the following to get the information that i need

```
details = response.json()
checkIntent = details["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"][0]["elements"]

if len(checkIntent) == 0:
  print("No intent found, nothing is classified")
       return False
else:
       return True
```

This code works 80% of the time. The problem is that sometimes i get

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What i have noticed is that when trying to get the response sometimes details["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"] itself is null. I have tried to use isIntances and other methods but none of them work for me.

Currently i have implemented sleep for 10 seconds before getting the response, but that is not a good solution, cause most of the cases the proper response comes within 4-5 seconds.

How do i make this robust enough so that I can get the desired results without sleep.

Comment: try to use proxy, or add checking if you don't get correct json resent your request again. But better to use different proxy and retry on the same time.

Comment: @dimay could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Try checking the resulting status of the response rather than assuming you have data.  its possible you are getting errors and just plowing along assuming you got your json back as you expect.

Comment: If *details["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"]* is evaluating to None you need to find out if that's an expected response from the API. If not, then the API is broken. If there is a reason why it might be None then just test for it and process accordingly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
details = response.json()         
if not details["itineraryIntent"]:             
   time.sleep(7)             
   response2 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)             
   details2 = response2.json()             
   checkIntent = details2["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"][0]["elements"]         
else:             
   checkIntent = details["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"][0]["elements"]         
   if len(checkIntent) == 0:             
      print("No intent found, nothing is classified")             
      return False         
   else:              
      return True
```

Comment: you should add comments to this answer. its just there with no explanation.

Comment: You also need to format your answer sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different proxy (https://github.com/andigwandi/free-proxy) per each request. In case when you don't get correct response (`json`) resend your request again:

```
# Replace these values with your proxy information
proxy_host = 'your_proxy_host'
proxy_port = 'your_proxy_port'

# Define the proxy dictionary
proxy_dict = {
    'http': f'http://{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}',
    'https': f'https://{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}',
}

response = requests.get/post(url, proxies=proxy_dict_with_auth, ...)

details = response.json()
userNodes = details["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"]

if not userNodes:
    # change proxy
    proxy_host = 'your_proxy_host'
    proxy_port = 'your_proxy_port'

    # Define the proxy dictionary
    proxy_dict = {
        'http': f'http://{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}',
        'https': f'https://{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}',
    }

    response = requests.get/post(url, proxies=proxy_dict_with_auth, ...)

.....
```

But better to use official API.

Comment: you should add checking on the status code on the response rather then trying to reference something that may not be there...

Comment: I see what you are getting at. if i do not find the value then i am going to wait and call the request again, hoping that gives me the data that i want

Comment: @LhasaDad i am checking on the response status. only if it is 200 i am reaching the above step

Comment: `details = response.json()
        if not details["itineraryIntent"]:
            time.sleep(7)
            response2 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            details2 = response2.json()
            checkIntent = details2["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"][0]["elements"]
        else:
            checkIntent = details["itineraryIntent"]["userNodes"][0]["elements"]
        if len(checkIntent) == 0:
            print("No intent found, nothing is classified")
            return False
        else:
             return True`
This helped

Comment: @RustomContractor have you tried printing response.text to see what you actually got back before trying to extract data from it?  just a thought to help debug.